# Is 510511 the smallest Euclid number $ E_n$ that divides by the next prime $ p_{n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, products

That is $ 2.3.5.7.11.13.17+1 = 19.97.277$.
So I looking for examples of the form;
$ 2.3.5…...p_n +1 = p_{n+1}.m$.
Looking at a table of explicit factorizations, from https://oeis.org/A038507/a038507.txt
at ‘The online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences’, there are no more examples on the list, which covers the first 60 primes.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number , and

https://oeis.org/A006862

I tried to use Wilson’s Theorem but couldn’t get this to work.

Comment: I just found that $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot\ldots\cdot 176078267 - 1$ is divisible by the next prime $176078293$. (Note $-1$, not $+1$.)

Answer (score 2):

$\prod_{i<1} p_i + 1 = 2$ is divisible by $p_1 = 2$ (an empty product is $1$ by convention).

$\prod_{i<2} p_i + 1 = 3 $ is divisible by $p_2 = 3$

If you don't count those, the first example is yours:

$\prod_{i<8} p_i + 1$ is divisible by $p_8$

The next examples are $p_{233}$ and $p_{431}$.

EDIT: There are no more such $p_n$ for $n \le 10000$.

Heuristically, $\prod_{i<n} p_i + 1$ has probability approximately $1/p_n$ of being divisible by $p_n$.  Since the series $\sum_{n} 1/p_n$ diverges, we should expect there to be infinitely many such $p_n$.  However, this is not a proof. Moreover, the series diverges very slowly, so these $p_n$ are likely to be very sparse.  The next $n$ could easily be in the billions.

EDIT: [Sequence A338543](https://oeis.org/A338543) is now in OEIS.